# streamReader inside OnChanged fires twice?

Tags: c#, onchange, streamreader, filesystemwatcher, opentext

I have a small application that watches a specific file and whenever it changes, my application should do the actions in the loop, but something is firing the function more than once!! here's my code

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.FullPath == @"C:\test.txt")
    {
        string textFilePath = @"C:\test.txt";

        try
        {
            using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(textFilePath))
            {
                var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    //actions here
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm guessing in the loop when streamreader do File.OpenText somehow is firing the function again?! any ideas?

Comment: I only made it empty for debugging, I promise this is not my final code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
So I did one small thing that controlled the issue, I added a counter and always check if it's not the first time, skip and reassign it to 0.

```
private int fireCounter = 0;

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        fireCounter++;

        if (fireCounter == 1)
        {
            delete();

            if (e.FullPath == @"C:\test.txt")
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                //I added Sleep for two seconds because without it sometimes it wont work

                string textFilePath = @"C:\test.txt";
                try
                {
                    using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(textFilePath))
                    {
                        var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        foreach (var line in lines)
                        {
                            //Actions Here
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fireCounter = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, I had it already before you answered me, as I said in my previous comment that `NotifyFilter.Size` didn't really help and I already had `NotifyFilter.LastWrite`  which is firing twice first when the file is really updated, second when `streamReader = File.OpenText(textFilePath)` so the only solution was to control the second trigger

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Changed event is raised when changes are made to the size, system attributes, last write time, **last access time**, ...

So yes, opening (actually: closing) the file will raise the Changed event again.

You can use the [NotifyFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to limit the actions your watcher triggers on.

Comment: Thank you! I used `NotifyFilter.Size ` and it worked, my only issue now if the update of the file was the same size it wont work! for example:
the file was: test1
and the update is: test2
it won't change the size! and if I put `watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastWrite; ` it will be fired twice :/

Comment: nevermind, I made something that helped.. I'll update my question with the solution

Comment: Okay, thank you.. I posted the solution as an answer